# ¿Por qué en algunos sitios se le dice «abanico» al «ventilador»?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

Soy de la parte noroeste de México, nacido a principios de los 80', y todo mundo llama abanico a lo que, en otras partes del país, se le dice ventilador.

La mayoría de la gente (de mi entorno y de toda la ciudad) era de clase muy baja y migrantes con no más de 30 años de asentamiento, **mi hipótesis** es que se le comenzó a llamar abanico a los ventiladores porque `fueron los primeros aparatos que sustituyeron al instrumento manual.`

Se me viene el recuerdo que poca gente tenía *coolers* y los aparatos de aire acondicionado (llamados mas comúnmente "refrigeración") eran casi exclusivos a clase media/alta y oficinas. Posiblemente estos aparatos comenzaron a popularizarse hasta los 90, cuando yo era adolescente tan nuevo era el auge, que uno de mis propósitos era ser técnico en refrigeraciones.

Comment: En mi pais, Cuba, siempre he escuchado "ventilador" para referirse a estos, y ninguna otra palabra. Tu hipotesis me parece bastante correcta, mas alla de que no pueda corroborarla. He buscado y no he encontrado referencias sobre el tema. Asi que supongo que sea algo muy de tu localidad. Sabes si en otras regiones de Mexico tambien se usa este termino?

Comment: Bueno... si hay referencias https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/abanico-ventilador.249206/#post-1700968. Esto tambien puede haber surgido del hecho que se use `fan` en ingles para referirse a ambos

Comment: Puede ser que tambien se le diga abanico en otros paises, como en Panama. https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120814114113AAh8CTm

Comment: En Veracruz, México, se le dice abanico al ventilador. En Puerto Rico también se usa abanico en vez de ventilador.

Answer (score 3):

**Fan** significa tanto *abanico* como *ventilador* en el idioma inglés, teniendo esto en cuenta creo muy posible que cuanto más próximo a un país de habla inglesa nos encontremos, más frecuentemente se utilicen términos incorrectos derivados de la traducción directa.

Comment: Puede ser. Pero segun https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120814114113AAh8CTm  tambien se utiliza en Panama para refirse a ambos

Comment: @Theia Pero Panamá tiene una influencia estadounidense muy fuerte, debido al canal, así que esto encajaría con la hipótesis de Javier.

Comment: es muy probable que tenga más qué ver la influencia estadunidense.

Answer (score 2):

En mi país, Colombia, se dice de las dos formas, pero depende de la región, en los departamentos de la costa caribe la más usada es "abanico", y en el resto del país "ventilador", la razón de esto no la sé.

La verdad el invento del "abanico de mano" (el de moda) es un invento pésimo, porque fácilmente uno podría tomar cualquier cosa de su casa que sea dura y plana y usarla como abanico, y así no gastar dinero.

Es muy, pero muy poco común encontrar a un colombiano usar un abanico de mano, mi mamá se compró uno hace unos años, y casi nunca lo usó.

Comment: Bienvenido Jesu. También soy colombiano y no estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices.En la costa oirás abanico pero en Antioquia oirás ventilador. Además en Bogotá o Pasto no verás nadie usando un abanico de mano pero en Lorica o Montería vas a ver muchos.